# Jenkins Master Memory Issues

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, cicd, jenkins-kubernetes

Our jenkins is running in kubernetes. The memory limit for jenkins-master is 10GB, curreltly its using 9.1GB. Even if i'm not running any pipleine the memory will be same. So I restarted and the memory usage decresed to 3GB, I have set up prometheus for monitoring.
I will list out todays memory data.

| Time | Memory |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 9.04GB |
| 11:00 | 9.08GB |
| 12:00 | 9.11GB |
| 14:00 | 9.14GB |
| 16:00 | 9.18GB |
| 19:00 | 9.18GB |
| 20:00 | 9.04GB |

I'm not sure why this type of memory change happens.

Looking for the insights to do next level of debugging